# Add Pickimage, Crop with 1:4 & Replace drawab.image - Howto?

Tags: android, image, replace, crop

I'm trying to add Pick image with Crop feature by aspect 1:4, it's 2000 width, 500 height => 1:4, and i want the selected image by user to replace an image located in drawable/custom_image.jpg.
Note : the image "custom_image" isn't showed as imageview in the app.
I've searched Stackoverflow, and found the ways, but i'm having a problem with cropping it & replacing that selected image with "R.drawable.custom_image".

EDIT : Forgot the cropping, got problems in it, i just need the replace drawable code in OnActivityResult.

I've created a button, when pressed it calls a method, here's the code :

```
    Button mSelectbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.selectimage);
    mSelectbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SelectImageActivity(v);
        }
    });
```

SelectImageActivity :

public void SelectImageActivity(View v) {

```
Intent selectintent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
selectintent.setType("image/*");
selectintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(selectintent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

}

And here's the method :

```
OnActivityResult Code : 
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Drawable imageView = (Drawable)findViewById(R.drawable.custom_header);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header);
    }
    }
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this library to tackle this problem because keeping outputx etc.. is not working for some versions of android:

Add this library to gradle:

```
//image cropping library to show as square for android older versions to work
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
```

this method performs cropping:

```
private void performCrop(Uri mImageCaptureUri) {
//this creates a new image file comment below  if you want file creation code
    Uri destinationUri = MediaUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(GlobalConstants.CREATE_IMAGE);

    Crop.of(mImageCaptureUri,destinationUri).asSquare().start(getActivity(),this);
}
```

In your on activity result you can get Cropped image catch it:

```
if(requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
                Uri outPutImageUri = Crop.getOutput(data);
```

Comment below if you want any futher info

Comment: Gonna try it out, but for making aspect ratio, how ? can i make it with this library ?

Comment: Tested it, got a lot of problems, anyway never mind about "crop" i will make the user make 2000w, 500h.
Still one thing, in "OnActivityResult", how to type " replace the selected image with R.drawable.custom_image" ?
check the op, i've added the OnActivityResult code.

Comment: You want to replace the existing imageview placeholder with the selected image?

Comment: Yes, but the image i want to replace isn't displayed in the App.
What i'm doing is a Xposed Module, which change a color to drawable, which is SystemUI Header, and i want to add an option to replace that image with the selected image by user.

Comment: Okay, There is a library called Picasso(you might have heard about it), Its a good library for image related operations using that you can load the local image into your imageview as below:        Picasso.with(context).load(new File(attachment.getAttachmentLocation())).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder2).into(productImageViewHolder.productImage);

Comment: I recommend you to use picasso library as it is useful for asynchronous image loading and also getting rid of Bitmap OutOfMemoryExceptions, you can crop the image, transform etc.. refer its documentation for more info

Comment: Gonna try it out, and let you know. Thanks a lot mate!